# How to add git repo path in the Dockerfile?

Tags: git, docker

Can someone please tell me how to add the git repo path in the Dockerfile. Here is my Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.3
MAINTAINER Upendra Devisetty

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++ \
            make \
            git \
            zlib1g-dev \
            python \
            wget \
            curl \
            python-matplotlib \
            python-numpy \
            python-pandas


ENV BINPATH /usr/bin
RUN git clone https://upendra_35@bitbucket.org/upendra_35/evolinc_docker.git
RUN chmod +x /evolinc_docker/evolinc-part-I.sh && cp /evolinc_docker/evolinc-part-I.sh $BINPATH

RUN wget -O- http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/assets/downloads/cufflinks-2.2.1.Linux_x86_64.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
RUN wget -O- https://github.com/TransDecoder/TransDecoder/archive/2.0.1.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
RUN wget -O- http://seq.cs.iastate.edu/CAP3/cap3.linux.x86_64.tar | tar vfx -
RUN curl ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/executables/blast+/LATEST/ncbi-blast-2.3.0+-x64-linux.tar.gz > ncbi-blast-2.3.0+-x64-linux.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf ncbi-blast-2.3.0+-x64-linux.tar.gz
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
RUN tar -zxvf Python-2.7.10.tgz
RUN cd Python-2.7.10 && ./configure && make
RUN cd ..
RUN wget -O- http://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/q/qu/quast/quast-3.0.tar.gz | tar zxvf -
RUN wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/bio-bwa/files/latest/download?source=files && tar xvf download\?source\=files
RUN cd bwa-0.7.12 && make
RUN cd ..

ENV PATH /cufflinks-2.2.1.Linux_x86_64/:$PATH
ENV PATH /TransDecoder-2.0.1/:$PATH
ENV PATH /CAP3/:$PATH
ENV PATH /ncbi-blast-2.3.0+/bin/:$PATH
ENV PATH /Python-2.7.10/:$PATH
ENV PATH /bedtools2-2.25.0/bin/:$PATH
ENV PATH /samtools-bcftools-htslib-1.0_x64-linux/bin/:$PATH
ENV PATH /bwa-0.7.12/:$PATH

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/evolinc-part-I.sh"]
CMD ["-h"]
```

When i run this

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/working-dir -w /working-dir ubuntu/evolinc -c AthalianaslutteandluiN30merged.gtf -g TAIR10_chr.fasta -r TAIR10_cdna_20110103_representative_gene_model_updated.fa -b TE_RNA_transcripts.fa -t AnnotatedPEATPeaks.gff -x Atha_known_lncRNAs.mod.gff
```

I'm getting this error

```
python: can't open file 'get_gene_length_filter.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What i don't understand is how do i add the git rep to the path so that all the scripts in the repo can be opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing `RUN git clone https://upendra_35@bitbucket.org/upendra_35/evolinc_docker.git` without ever specifying *where* it will be cloned.

Same for the `wget` commands.

You might want to set a `WORKDIR` first instead of dumping everything in, by default, `/`. See [Dockerfile `WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir).

Your script [`evolinc-part-I.sh`](https://bitbucket.org/upendra_35/evolinc_docker/src/c64709622a366d2075de8299f479284463aef04e/evolinc-part-I.sh?fileviewer=file-view-default) might expect to find those resource in a specific path: if you were able to make that script work in your local machine (without docker), compare with your image by running a container with a bash, to explore what was installed where.

Comment: After cloning the git repo, i added this line `RUN cd evolinc_docker` but still i'm getting the same error. Can you please give me an example of Dockerfile where the WORKDIR is specified. I'm very new to this.

Comment: @upendra the doc itself is quite clear: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir. Also the best practice recommends it over a cd: https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir. See more at http://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker_Dockerfile_to_build_images_automatically_5_WORKDIR_ENV_ADD_ENTRYPOINT.php

Comment: Thanks again. I'm still having the issues but will keep trying